How to correctly identify entity types for tokens using spaCy using python?
I'm using spaCy to extract and identify entity types (like ORG, GPE, DATE, etc.) from a text description. However, I am noticing some incorrect results, and I'm unsure how to fix this.
Here is the code I am using:
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def getPayeeName(description):
    description = description.replace("-", " ").replace("/", " ").strip()
    doc = nlp(description)

    for token in doc:
        print(f"Token: {token.text}, Entity: {token.ent_type_ if token.ent_type_ else 'None'}")

# Example input
description = "UPI DR 400874707203 BENGALORE 08 JAN 2024 14:38:56 MEDICAL LTD HDFC 50200"
getPayeeName(description)

Token: UPI, Entity: ORG
Token: DR, Entity: ORG
Token: 400874707203, Entity: None
Token: BENGALORE, Entity: None
Token: 08, Entity: DATE
Token: JAN, Entity: DATE
Token: 2024, Entity: DATE
Token: 14:38:56, Entity: None
Token: MEDICAL, Entity: ORG
Token: LTD, Entity: ORG
Token: HDFC, Entity: ORG
Token: 50200, Entity: ORG

50200 is identified as ORG, but it is just a number.

BENGALORE is a city, but it is not recognized as a GPE or location
(returns None).

UPI and DR are acronyms/abbreviations, but they are incorrectly
identified as ORG.


I want the entity recognition to be more accurate and reliable.
How can I fix these issues? Are there additional spaCy configurations, custom rules, or pre-trained models I should use to improve the entity recognition?
Note: I tried ChatGPT as well, but still this issue is not solved.

Frankly even a human could not do the full NER on your example. Actually chat GPT 4o was not so bad except that it saw it as a bank transaction but if you give it some context or some examples, I guess that the result could be interesting.

If you have tried GPT for the same task and you are still facing same issue. Then no other Pre-trained model is going to work. Because GPT right now now is far superior then other Pre-trained model.
And most of the Bert based NER model are not fine tuned for Indian based dataset. And that is the reason you see incorrect result.
And the 2nd reason is insufficient context. The example that you provided has not sufficient context. Not even human can tell what does your example is about. And if you try to make your example meaningful then passing modified example to already used model will give better result. And having correct context is prerequisite because most of these deep learning model do prediction based on context word.

I am adding one code which might work for you because it was fine tune on Indian dataset.
Code:
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification, pipeline

# Checking if GPU is available
device = 0 if torch.cuda.is_available() else -1  # GPU: 0, CPU: -1

# Load pre-trained tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Venkatesh4342/NER-Indian-xlm-roberta")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("Venkatesh4342/NER-Indian-xlm-roberta")

# Initiating NER Model
ner_pipeline = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=device)

# Example data
input_text = "UPI DR 400874707203 BENGALORE 08 JAN 2024 14:38:56 MEDICAL LTD HDFC 50200"

# Calling NER Model
results = ner_pipeline(input_text)

# Display the output
for entity in results:
    print(f"Entity: {entity['word']}, Label: {entity['entity']}, Confidence: {entity['score']:.2f}")

Final Output:
Entity: ▁U, Label: organization, Confidence: 0.99
Entity: PI, Label: organization, Confidence: 0.99
Entity: ▁DR, Label: organization, Confidence: 0.99
Entity: ▁BEN, Label: location, Confidence: 0.76
Entity: GAL, Label: location, Confidence: 0.83
Entity: ORE, Label: location, Confidence: 0.79
Entity: ▁MEDI, Label: organization, Confidence: 1.00
Entity: CAL, Label: organization, Confidence: 0.99
Entity: ▁LTD, Label: organization, Confidence: 1.00
Entity: ▁HD, Label: organization, Confidence: 0.99
Entity: FC, Label: organization, Confidence: 0.98

The final output is little better and after post processing logic you can combine the broken word together as well.
Final note: I would suggest to go for fine tuning a NER based model on your data. And try to have meaningful context

Thanks for helping me for this problem. Now i got an some idea, only NLP and NER won't help. so I'm planning to add some REGEX pattern and ignored some unwanted words like numbers,date,accronym etc.. then i will apply NLP and NER. In this way i can able to increase the accuracy
